# Having Trouble Assigning an Outlook Category to a MailItem with VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, categories

I have put together a vba script (that runs in ThisOutlookSession) that monitors MailItems added to my sent folder, and when it detects a project number in the subject, it copies that MailItem to a shared mailbox location automatically based on that project number.

The scripts works well, however I would like to categorize all MailItems copied/moved by the script, so that users will have a visual indication to which messages were automatically moved by the script (since the end product will run invisible in the background).

I'm missing something somewhere as its not assigning the category at the end of my script. Below is my full script (including my attempt to assign the mailitem to a category, which is under the " 'Assigns Category to Mailitem " comment). Any help, insight or direction will be immensely appreciated:

---

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

Private CancelLoop As Boolean
Private DupSubject As String

Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
  Set olApp = Outlook.Application


  Set InboxItems = GetNS(olApp).GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
  Set Items = GetNS(olApp).GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)

    'Start Loop Check - Compares to last moved mailitem
    If item.Subject = DupSubject Then
        CancelLoop = True
    End If

    If (CancelLoop) Then
        MsgBox ("Ending Script (Loop Detected)")
        CancelLoop = False
        Exit Sub
    End If

  On Error Resume Next

  MsgBox "New item in the SENT Folder, Checking for T-#"

  Dim EmailSub As String
  Dim EmailSubArr As Variant
  Dim ProjectNum As String
  Dim FullProjectNum As String
  Dim ProjNumLen As Long
  Dim ParentFolderName As String
  Dim SubFolderName As String


    If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
        'Checks Email Subject for Project Number Tag
        If InStr(item.Subject, "T-") > 0 Then

            MsgBox "T-# Detected"



            'Splits out Project Number into an Array for Extraction
            EmailSub = item.Subject
            EmailSubArr = Split(EmailSub, Chr(32))

              For i = LBound(EmailSubArr) To UBound(EmailSubArr)
                  If InStr(EmailSubArr(i), "T-") > 0 Then

                      FullProjectNum = EmailSubArr(i)
                      MsgBox "T-# Extracted"
                      ProjNumLen = Len(FullProjectNum)

                      MsgBox ("T-# is " & ProjNumLen & " Characters Long")

                      'Project Number Length Check and Formatting

                      If ProjNumLen >= 11 Then
                        Exit Sub
                      End If

                      If ProjNumLen <= 6 Then
                        Exit Sub
                      End If

                      If ProjNumLen = 10 Then
                      'Really Extended T-# Format 1(ie T-38322X12)
                      ProjectNum = Right(FullProjectNum, 8)
                      ParentFolderName = Left(ProjectNum, 2)
                      SubFolderName = Left(ProjectNum, 8)
                      End If

                      If ProjNumLen = 9 Then
                      'Extended T-# Format 1(ie T-38322X1)
                      ProjectNum = Right(FullProjectNum, 7)
                      ParentFolderName = Left(ProjectNum, 2)
                      SubFolderName = Left(ProjectNum, 7)
                      End If

                      If ProjNumLen = 8 Then
                      'Uncommon T-# Format (ie T-38322A)
                      ProjectNum = Right(FullProjectNum, 6)
                      ParentFolderName = Left(ProjectNum, 2)
                      SubFolderName = Left(ProjectNum, 6)
                      End If

                      If ProjNumLen = 7 Then
                      'Standard T-# Format (ie T-38322)
                      ProjectNum = Right(FullProjectNum, 5)
                      ParentFolderName = Left(ProjectNum, 2)
                      SubFolderName = Left(ProjectNum, 5)
                      End If

                      Exit For

                  End If
              Next i

            MsgBox ("Confirm Extraction (1 of 3) - Project Number is T-" & ProjectNum)
            MsgBox ("Confirm Extraction (2 of 3) - Parent Folder Will Be " & ParentFolderName)
            MsgBox ("Confirm Extraction (3 of 3) - Sub Folder Will Be " & SubFolderName)
            MsgBox ("Will Now Perform Folder Checks")

            'Perform Folder Checks, Creates Folders When Needed

            Dim fldrparent As Outlook.MAPIFolder
            Dim fldrsub As Outlook.MAPIFolder

            Set fldrparent = Outlook.Session.Folders("Projects").Folders("Project Root").Folders(ParentFolderName)
            Set fldrsub = Outlook.Session.Folders("Projects").Folders("Project Root").Folders(ParentFolderName).Folders(SubFolderName)

            If fldrparent Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox "Parent Folder Does Not Exist, Creating Folder"
                Set fldrparent = Outlook.Session.Folders("Projects").Folders("Project Root").Folders.Add(ParentFolderName)
            Else
                MsgBox "Parent Folder Already Exists, Do Nothing"
            End If

            If fldrsub Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox "Sub Folder Does Not Exist, Creating Folder"
                Set fldrsub = Outlook.Session.Folders("Projects").Folders("Project Root").Folders(ParentFolderName).Folders.Add(SubFolderName)
            Else
                MsgBox "Sub Folder Already Exists, Do Nothing"
            End If

            'Moves Copy of Email to Folder

            MsgBox "Copying Sent Email to Project Folder"

            Dim myCopiedItem As Outlook.MailItem
            Dim FolderDest As Outlook.MAPIFolder

            Set myCopiedItem = item.Copy
            Set FolderDest = Outlook.Session.Folders("Projects").Folders("Project Root").Folders(ParentFolderName).Folders(SubFolderName)

            item.Move FolderDest
            MsgBox "Copy Complete"

            'Assigns Category to Mailitem
            item.Categories = "Copied2Projects"
            item.save


            'Duplicate Email/Loop Check
            DupSubject = EmailSub

            Set objExplorer = Nothing

        Else
        MsgBox "Did not detect T-##### project number"
        End If

    End If

End Sub

Function GetNS(ByRef app As Outlook.Application) As Outlook.NameSpace
  Set GetNS = app.GetNamespace("MAPI")
End Function
```

Comment: Forgot to mention (in case its relevant), all users will be using Outlook 2007 or higher.

Comment: Try moving the category assignment and save before you move it.

Comment: Wow, that worked! Never would have guessed the placement mattered. Thank you so much! I was pounding my head against the wall for a bit there!

Comment: I added an answer with a bit more explanation (and an alternative)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
        Dim myCopiedItem As Outlook.MailItem
        item.Move FolderDest
        MsgBox "Copy Complete"

        'Assigns Category to Mailitem
        item.Categories = "Copied2Projects"
        item.save
```

Outlook does weird things when you move an item, effectively creating a new item you no longer have access to if you don't do something to track it. There are a few ways to fix this problem.

You can just move the code saving prior to the `.Move` command and avoid this problem entirely.

Otherwise, you can try something like

```
Set myCopiedItem = item.Move(FolderDest)
myCopiedItem.Categories = "Copied2Projects"
myCopiedItem.save
```

which should also work.

This drove me NUTS for a long time with a related problem once upon a time...